# Wrap div around changeable html and close off even when the inner html isnt closed correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where the client needs to be able to insert html he is copying off other sites into a product description.

He has no clue about html so he is literally copying it off the site with the permission of suppliers and then pasting into an Opencart description.

The issue is that sometimes what he is copying isnt correctly formatted and so it may be closing divs too early or not closing them at all making the html for the remainder of the page all over the place.

Is it possible to have a situation where i can create div and basically tell it **Close off this div here no matter what the html inside it contains**?

Thanks.

I guess just to give an example. In this situation the bottom `</div>` would not close off `<div class="myclosedoffdiv">` even though thats what Id like it to do.

```
<div class="myclosedoffdiv">
   <div><span> This is incorrectly formatted html</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope...this is not a programming issue...it's a client-training one.

Comment: hmmmm, not sure id like to write it off as his request would have been the ability to do that. Perhaps saying no is the only answer but i would like to think there is a workaround before ruling it out. Training him on html isnt the road i want to go down.

Comment: This isn't like a quick fix. You're bascially having to validate the code on input and then correct it automatically. Both (if even possible) would be very intensive javascript. Ideally, he should only be able to add text and your input process should format it into the right shape.

Comment: maybe it would be better to use something like [tinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) and get him to copy the text rather than HTML. That way he can edit and reformat it if it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create jquery object from string (in case if using jquery):

```
var div = $('<div><span> This is incorrectly formatted html</span>');
```

`div[0]` will return:

```
<div><span> This is incorrectly formatted html</span></div>
```

then insert it into wrapper:

```
$('.myclosedoffdiv').html(div);
```

Comment: Wow thanks, wasnt expecting to work but tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/5f7d6sgo/1/